# Strange behavior implementing long polling in NODE.JS

Tags: node.js

I have this node.js code to implement a "long poll":

```
var lpres1; // store the response object globally

// accept long poll call that will block until released by lp_free1 call
app.get('/API/lp1', (req, res) => {
  lpres1 = res;  // store response object so we can respond later
 
});

// free up long poll call response and also send the response to this call
app.get('/API/lp_free1', (req, res) => {

  lpres1.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  lpres1.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
  lpres1.status(200).send("OK from LP1").end();


  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
  res.status(200).send("OK").end();


});
```

- I open two browser tabs
- In the first I call "localhost:8080/API/lp1" and the browser blocks (as expected)
- In the second tab I call "localhost:8080/API/lp_free1" and the response in browser one returns "OK from LP1" and the second browser "OK". This is all as expected: happy days.

where I see strange behavior:

- I open three browser tabs
- In the first I call "localhost:8080/API/lp1" and the browser blocks (as expected)
- In the second I call "localhost:8080/API/lp1" and the browser blocks (here I expect the global variable lpres1 to be overwritten by this call and would lose the ability to respond to the first call - but no!)
- In the third tab I call "localhost:8080/API/lp_free1" and the response in browser one returns "OK from LP1". I expected browser two to return
- THEN I make the call in browser three again to lp_free1. This time browser two returns! As there is only one global variable I am using, how is node.js magically able to respond to the other browser??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is browser weirdness.  When you make the second request to the exact same URL `http://localhost:8080/API/lp1`, the browser says to itself: "Gee I already have a request out to that URL so I'll wait for that one to finish before sending this next one and maybe if I get luck, I can use a cached result from the first one to satisfy the second one.

You can bypass that attempt to cache the result in several ways (by turning off caching), but also by just adding a unique query parameter to the end of the URL such as: `http://localhost:8080/API/lp1?t=1` for the first URL and `http://localhost:8080/API/lp1?t=2` for the second URL.  This way the browser won't think they are the same request and will send them separately.

There are other browser limitations too that could be relevant in this type of testing.  The browser will limit the number of outstanding requests to the exact same host.  So, if you have long running requests (like these), you can very easily run into that limit if you make many of them in the same browser.  In that case, it will queue up subsequent requests until a prior one finishes so as not to overwhelm a host with too many requests from the same client.  I don't remember exactly what this limit is and it may vary slightly from one browser to the next, but I think it's around 5 requests at once max to the same host.

P.S. I hope this server code is just for experimenting because using a module-level variable like `lpres1` will never work with multiple clients accessing the server as they will trounce each other's state.  Usually client-specific state (which is what your long running connection is) will be stored in something like a server-side session that is keyed to a particular client.  So one client can't stomp on the other client's data or connections.

Comment: Thanks - you were spot on, doing as suggested resulted in expected behavior.